# Table is not styling correctly when name is long

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I'm having an issue with styling a table on my site. check out [my site](http://ratemymechanic.us) and if you search for "Rochester, mn", scroll down and you can see that if the name is long, as in the case for Tilson's Automotive and Goodyear, it falls below the image. I would rather have the text wrap than have the entire thing drop below the image. Anybody know how I can fix this? It's occuring on Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the max-width on the `<a>` tag that is the mechanic's name to be the widest it can be (around 175px).

Comment: That makes the text wrap, but if you do that, every name is floated below the image to the left. I want the text to still be to the right of the image, but wrap if necessary.

Comment: @Catfish try using max-width and setting it to 175px

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by removing the `float:left` in the following places:

- `#results table tbody tr td div`
- `#results table tbody tr td:first-child span`
- `#results table tbody tr td a`
- `#results table tbody tr td div.mechanicDiv`

To move the `span` to its own line, you could add `display:block`.

Comment: You will still need to edit your margins and spacing to get the desired positioning.

Answer (score 0):

```
#results table tbody tr td div.mechanicDiv {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 184px;
}
```

184px was the max width i found.